# Anyone know of an Erlang pubsubhubbub subscriber client?

Tags: erlang, websub

Anyone know of an Erlang [pubsubhubbub](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/) subscriber client?

Comment: PubSub is different from PubSubHubbub (PuSH).

Comment: if possible "ire_and_curses" should revisit as I think they were confused and conflated the two protocols, it is easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

I present you with a (most likely incomplete) list of pubsub implementations (one of them is even written in Erlang):
http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/wiki/Hubs 
Google = tech :)
Also, you should probably go back and mark some (or all) of your questions answered.

Comment: The have a single erlang experimental pub hub and subscriber -- I'm really just looking for a subscriber only client.

Answer (score 1):

Searching in [projects.trapexit.org](http://projects.trapexit.org) for "pubsub" this is what you get:
[alt text http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/1835/screenshot20100523at124.png](http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/1835/screenshot20100523at124.png).

Maybe one of these could help you.